# Python dataframe - ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, tuples

I am getting this cryptic error message while trying to access columns of a Pandas DataFrame which uses tuples as columns name.

Here is a simple example to illustrate and reproduce the problem:

-INITIALIZATION-

```
testDataFrame=pd.DataFrame(np.array([[8,1,2,3,9]]),columns=['Id1',(1, 'one'),(2, 'two'),(3, 'three'),'Id2'],dtype="object")
```

-TESTS-

```
testDataFrame[["Id2","Id1"]] #works

testDataFrame[["Id1","Id1"]] #works

testDataFrame[[(1, 'one'),"Id1"]] #works

testDataFrame[["Id1",(1, 'one')]] #return ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence
```

Do you know what's wrong with the order of the columns name ? Why is this error popping up?

Thanks in advance for your insights!

**EDIT1:** My pandas version is: **0.23.4**

**EDIT2:**

Here is the entire error message I am getting:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-219-c5f714c2b560> in <module>
----> 1 testDataFrame[["Id1",(1, 'one')]]

~/anaconda3/envs/deep-learning/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py in __getitem__(self, key)
   2680         if isinstance(key, (Series, np.ndarray, Index, list)):
   2681             # either boolean or fancy integer index
-> 2682             return self._getitem_array(key)
   2683         elif isinstance(key, DataFrame):
   2684             return self._getitem_frame(key)

~/anaconda3/envs/deep-learning/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py in _getitem_array(self, key)
   2707     def _getitem_array(self, key):
   2708         # also raises Exception if object array with NA values
-> 2709         if com.is_bool_indexer(key):
   2710             # warning here just in case -- previously __setitem__ was
   2711             # reindexing but __getitem__ was not; it seems more reasonable to

~/anaconda3/envs/deep-learning/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/core/common.py in is_bool_indexer(key)
    113     elif isinstance(key, list):
    114         try:
--> 115             arr = np.asarray(key)
    116             return arr.dtype == np.bool_ and len(arr) == len(key)
    117         except TypeError:  # pragma: no cover

~/anaconda3/envs/deep-learning/lib/python3.5/site-packages/numpy/core/numeric.py in asarray(a, dtype, order)
    499 
    500     """
--> 501     return array(a, dtype, copy=False, order=order)
    502 
    503 

ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence
```

Comment: For me working nice, what is your pandas version?

Comment: `testDataFrame[["Id1",(1, 'one')]]` works for me with no problem in pandas `.25.3`

Comment: Thanks for your answers, I added additional details to the question